# validate group level data with rules table

Tags: java, sql

I have data structure rules in a file. And input file data should follow these rules and if dont then needs to be captured.

Rules are given below

```
DataRecord|GroupNum|GroupDefination|MinGroupOccurrence|MaxGroupOccurrence|RecordDefination|MinRecordOccurrence|MaxRecordOccurrence
AAA|1|M|1|2|M|1|2
BBB|1|M|1|2|O|0|1
CCC|1|M|1|2|M|1|1
DDD|2|O|0|3|M|1|2
EEE|2|O|0|3|M|1|1
FFF|2|O|0|3|O|0|1
```

O represents Optional and M Mandatory

Under Group 1 there are three records AAA, BBB and CCC.

```
1st - This group is mandatory so it will definitely should come in input file data.
2nd - This group can occur min 1 time and max 2 times.
Lets say..if this group occurs two times. The data would be like this

1st occurrence of Group 1
AAA 1st occurrence of AAA
AAA This can occur upto two times (2nd occurrence of AAA)
BBB Its optional so it may be here or may not be here. But in this example of   input data its occurred
CCC Its mandatory and can occur only one time

2nd occurrence of Group 1

AAA 1st occurrence of AAA, second time didnt come. Not a problem because its range is from 1 to 2 and its mandtaory. So it should be here atleast one time.
BBB
```

In second occurrence of group CCC didnt come. But it should come because its mandatory data record. That needs to be captured

```
Here DataRecord is records
- GroupNum is Group number
- GroupDefination  is whether Group is mandatory or optional.
- MinGroupOccurrence and MaxGroupOccurrence is Min and Max number of occurrence of a group.
- RecordDefination tells whether record is mandatory or optional
- MinRecordOccurrence and MaxRecordOccurrence tells how many times a record can occur itself in a Group
```

Short story is, A group can have group of records and one record inside that group can occur multiple times. (Explained in above table of exact pattern)

My input data in a file is going to come like this

```
AAA
AAA
BBB
CCC
AAA
BBB
DDD
EEE
FFF
```

If you see my above given input data, According to Data definition table, Group 1 is mandatory and can occur upto two times and in that group record CCC is mandatory. But if you see in input data in second occurrence CCC didnt come. So at this point input data is not following data definition table rules. I need to capture that CCC data record of Group 1 of second occurrence is missed out.

My definition table is very big  and input data as well but just to get any simplified idea I have converted problem to a smaller level.

I need any idea how I can achieve this. I know basics of java but if I could get any idea than I can manage to write a code by myself.

Thanks

Comment: Your rules are very complicated to understand, can you share your code and expected input/output ?

Comment: @Ravi, Ravi could please tell where my information is short ? I will explain more in question ...

Comment: you should provide expected output for input and explain your expected output.

Comment: Expected output I have mentioned in my question. That I need to capture every thing from input file data which doesnt follow mentioned in rules. Given one example of CCC record that its missing and it should not happened because its mandatory record in Group 1 to happen. It came in first occurrence of group 1 but CCC missed out when group occurred second time. I hope its clear now..

Comment: CCC is missing ? where ? I can see it in your input data.

Comment: I'm still not getting your question. I think you need list of element where you are trying to find out which is present and/or absent ?